# Store passwords in putty

Tags: passwords, putty, password-management

How can I store my connection passwords in putty?

Comment: Its best to use kitty it does everything whatever we need.It store password and not needed to enter it again

Comment: I use [WinSCP](http://superuser.com/a/1020566/116475) to auto login in PuTTY with a password.

Answer (score 13):

I would suggest you use key-based authentication.  Then you can [use an agent to store your passphrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent).  For PuTTY, take a look at [pageant](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/pageant.exe).

Answer (score 12):

In Windows, you can create a shortcut which links to:

```
putty -load "Default Settings" -l username -pw password
```

Answer (score 9):

You can't, it's by design.

See [**Putty wish remember-passwords**](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/remember-password.html)

Answer (score 6):

> **A.2.8 Does PuTTY have the ability to remember my password so I don't have
>   to type it every time?**
>
> No, it doesn't.
>
> Remembering your password is a bad
>   plan for obvious security reasons:
>   anyone who gains access to your
>   machine while you're away from your
>   desk can find out the remembered
>   password, and use it, abuse it or
>   change it.
>
> In addition, it's not even possible
>   for PuTTY to automatically send your
>   password in a Telnet session, because
>   Telnet doesn't give the client
>   software any indication of which part
>   of the login process is the password
>   prompt. PuTTY would have to guess, by
>   looking for words like ‘password’ in
>   the session data; and if your login
>   program is written in something other
>   than English, this won't work.
>
> In SSH, remembering your password
>   would be possible in theory, but there
>   doesn't seem to be much point since
>   SSH supports public key
>   authentication, which is more flexible
>   and more secure. See chapter 8 in the
>   documentation for a full discussion of
>   public key authentication.

Comment: _"anyone who gains access to your machine while you're away from your desk can find out the remembered password"_ How is that different than someone who gains access to your machine and copies your PEM file?

Comment: if someone gains access to your machine while you're away you're already doing something wrong

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Kitty](http://kitty.9bis.com/), which is a fork of Putty.

Comment: Indeed Kitty saves the passwords. Does it saves them encryoted?

Comment: It saves them encryottled, but since kitty can decrypt them, anyone can.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem a while back, you can use [mRemote](http://www.mremote.org) as an SSH (as well as VNC, RDP and Citrix) client that does.

Comment: Does it saves the passwords encrypted?

Comment: mRemoteNG is a fork of mRemote and it is actively maintained, contrary to mRemote which seems that development stoped at 2008 http://www.mremoteng.org/

Answer (score 1):

I use .bat files like

```
putty root@66.66.66.66 -pw password
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [Tunnelier](http://www.bitvise.com/tunnelier) which supports saving passwords in profiles. It also functions as an SFTP client.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very bad idea.

It is impossible with Putty alone, as it spawns an actual Window. HOWEVER, if you feel that this is good idea for you for whatever reason, download the port of the ssh Linux client to Windows and pipe in the username/password.

Again that is a bad idea.

A GOOD IDEA would be to setup a set of keys, and this would allow for passwordless login.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Putty connection manager](http://blog.danwms.co.uk/2011/12/get-putty-connection-manager-here.html) which can be configured using a logon macro to login to servers automatically.

Comment: Notice: Link is broken.