# Is it possible to save a password with PUTTY?

Tags: linux, passwords, putty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to “auto login” in PuTTY with a password?](https://superuser.com/questions/44106/is-there-a-way-to-auto-login-in-putty-with-a-password)
>   [Store passwords in putty](https://superuser.com/questions/102993/store-passwords-in-putty)

I frequently use Putty, I know that possible save login like:

```
mylogin@server.name.com
```

But what about password? Does it possible also save password? Also I use pbrun, possible that after connect will be automatically executed pbrun with my credentials?
Each day I have connect to many servers hundreds times, so also small efficiency will be very useful.

Comment: For security reason no it isn't

Comment: But may be possible attach some script, something else? E.g. WinSCP allows save password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try mRemoteNG - it wraps puTTY and other apps/protocols in a handy user interface:

http://www.mremoteng.org/

Answer (score 5):

PuTTY for security reasons will not let you save the passwd of the session.

I would think that using keys instead of password for authentication will be a better solution, you can create a private/public key pair, install the private key in your desktop and the public keys in the remote servers you need access, that way you only have to load your key once and can access all the servers from there.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than saving a password, I would use switch to using [Public/Private Key authentication](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#pubkey); it has much the same effect. The provided link has a good tutorial on how and why to do things that way; I do everything they recommend there and I type my password once when Windows boots up, thus retaining good security.