# Why did windows update break WinSCP and PuTTY?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ssh, putty, winscp

I recently did an update to my windows 7 machine.  Before, I was able to connect to a linux server at school through WinSCP and PuTTY with no issues.  Now, I am either booted off after only a minute or so or I cannot connect at all.  These are the error messages that I have seen most often:

#### PuTTY

1. "Network error: Software caused connection to abort."  PuTTy goes inactive.
2. "Warning - Potential security breach.  Server's host key does not match the one PuTTY has cached in the registry. etc."  Sometimes allows me to enter the username and password.  Other times no...When it boots me it tells me that the server unexpectedly lost connection.

#### WinSCP

1. Sometimes it will allow me to enter the username but it will not accept the password and says "Access Denied."  Other times it will allow me in but then boot me shortly there after.
2. "Host is not communicating for more than 15 seconds. Still waiting."  Gives me an option to abort or wait for connection to establish.  Sometimes it does, most times it doesn't.  Once again if I do manage to get connected at all it boots me shortly there after.

Nothing is wrong with the server computer itself as far as I can tell.  Nothing changed there and other people are still able to access with no problem.  Therefore it must be my machine and was most likely caused by the windows update.  For what reasons could a windows update foul everything up and how can I fix the issue?

Comment: I've solved the similar problem. See my answer here
  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/294824/putty-network-error-software-caused-connection-abort/666975#666975

Answer (score 3):

Let's break down the problems.

1. WinSCP is a wrapper on PuTTy, so there is no point to debug it if you knows PuTTy is having problems.
2. It say server's host key does not match "some times" , it seems that your have 2 server hosting same ip, go the following registry to check, try clear the one you have problem and do connect again.

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\SshHostKeys
   ```
3. "Network error", go to the connection tab of PuTTy and try to adjust the values, see if it helps.
4. "server unexpectedly lost connection", that is a network issues. Try to ping the server and see if you can reach it when connection lost.

Comment: Oliver, Thanks for your suggestions.  #3 didn't help, unfortunately.  Can you clarify your second suggestion a little?  Is this registry supposed to be present on my Windows computer?  How do I access it?  Sorry I am a bit of a noob.  Also, for number 4, what do you mean by "pinging" the server?  How do I do this?  Thanks!

Comment: if you really can't understand "ping", i would suggest you to get a tech friends to your home and help you, you won't get this work.