# Putty error "Network error:Software caused connection abort"

Tags: ssh, putty, connection

I am trying to connect to host server using putty (for SSH). In putty I enter my server's IP and port as 22 and when click 'open' get this error of connection abort and putty becomes inactive. I tried changing the putty settings as suggested here ([PuTTY Network Error: Software caused connection abort](https://superuser.com/questions/294824/putty-network-error-software-caused-connection-abort)) but still the issue remains.

I don't even see the prompt to enter login credentials, connection is refused prior to that.
Called the tech support, they are able to connect via putty and informed me to check with my ISP.

Not able to understand what the issue is. Please help!

Comment: And you have "SSH" specified for the connection type? I know it may sound like a silly question, but sometimes people overlook something that may seem obvious. Presuming its not an inadvertent misconfiguration for the session, you could try clicking on "Logging" under "Session" and turn on session logging. You might find a clue in the log file after you receive the error that can help you isolate the problem.

Comment: Thanks moonpoint..but log file also doesn't say much except for the same error statements :(

Comment: Got it..my office network is blocking the connection. I am able to connect with my home net. Not sure what is the problem with my office network!

Comment: If you are trying to connect to an SSH server in the office network, then your connectivity may be blocked at a firewall or router. A firewall rule may be needed there permitting inbound SSH connections. If a router or firewall there is performing [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) might be needed, also. If you are attempting an outbound SSH connection from the office, instead, a firewall at the office might be blocking all but some specific types of outbound connections.

Comment: @karan: If your problem is solved, why not *answer* your question? Hey, you found the answer, so don't hesitate to add it yourself ... Furthermore, people will know your problem is solved, and accepting an answer even might earn you a few points ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think your connection is being blocked. It is probably intentional IT policy to block outbound ssh.

Source: Your comment

> "Got it..my office network is blocking the connection. I am able to connect with my home net. Not sure what is the problem with my office network! – karan ratnaparkhi Aug 1 '15 at 4:51"