# Another case of PuTTY: Software caused connnection abort

Tags: networking, ssh, putty

I am using my girlfriend's Windows 8 machine and trying to access a remote machine using ssh. Earlier today PuTTY was working fine, but then I uninstalled some programs that my girlfriend said she never used, and now I get the error "Network Error: Software caused connection abort". There is a question about this here that specifically concerns such issues after a period of inactivity:
[PuTTY Network Error: Software caused connection abort](https://superuser.com/questions/294824/putty-network-error-software-caused-connection-abort)

This is not the case here. It happens consistently after about a minute, whether or not there's any activity, including right in the middle of typing stuff.

There is no problem connecting to the Internet in general through a browser, and there's no problem connecting to the ssh server using ping. I don't think it's an issue with the particular site because I got the same problem sshing into a different machine.

Of the applications I uninstalled, none of them were system-type applications that should have changed the network settings (although this is Windows, so who knows ...). Reliability Monitor says I uninstalled the following apps: Playthru Player, 3CXPhone, eBay Worldwide, Dropbox 15GB. There was also an AOL app, some WildTangent games, Spotify, etc. (I can't remember exactly what the other ones were; is there a way to see *all* applications that were uninstalled through Programs and Features?)

I have tried:

- All the solutions mentioned on the page I linked to above (changing PuTTY's keepalive settings, `netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled`, setting `'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\TcpMaxDataRetransmissions` to 16)
- Using different ssh clients (KiTTY, also openssh from Cygwin; same problem in all of them)
- Different ssh servers

Nothing works. Any suggestions for how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: can you ping the server you're trying to connect to?

Comment: Yes, see comments above.

Comment: Are you on a potentially more protected network like a work or school network?

Comment: No. This used to work fine on the same computer, same network, same client and server, etc. The only thing that changed is that I uninstalled some software and rebooted.

Comment: OK, I rebooted again and this problem went away, so who knows what fixed it. Possibly one of the two settings I mentioned above (using netsh or the registry) didn't take effect till I rebooted, and fixed it.