# "Network error: Software caused connection abort" with Windows OpenSSH server

Tags: windows, putty, openssh, filezilla, winscp

I followed [this tutorial](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server) on installing an SFTP/SSH server on Windows, but I am having problems trying to connect to it. When using either PuTTY or WinSCP, I get the error "Network error: Software caused connection abort."

I had read that such errors are often caused by the server not being running (which I already checked), or problems with firewalls. The SSH server is behind a router, but I had already forwarded port 22 to this machine. I had also already made a firewall exception on the server for TCP connections on port 22.

I tried the top three solutions on [this page](https://superuser.com/questions/294824/putty-network-error-software-caused-connection-abort). None of the worked, and I believed the problem experienced by the person who posted this question was different from my own; I cannot even connect for a while.

Oddly, it appears that FileZilla works better. I am able to establish a connection (I followed [these](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Howto#SFTP_using_SSH2:_Key_based_authentication) steps), but the directory listings do not work properly (despite the fact that FileZilla displays 'Directory listing ... successful!") and give empty directories.

Is there anything else I can try (on either side) to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you connect from the server's machine? Show us FileZilla log (a real log file, not the message log from GUI), WinSCP session log and PuTTY event log.

Comment: @Martin Prikryl No, oddly enough, I cannot even connect from the server's machine.

Comment: Well, that's a more important information than most of the details in your question. Please update your question accordingly. + the logs.