# Windows firewall blocking SSH to secondary subnet

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, ssh, firewall

My network has 2 subnets /25 and Linux server in each subnet. One of the subnets contains a Windows computer which is used for managing Linux servers via SSH; but there is problem with firewall on this computer.The firewall allows communication within the same subnet but blocks communication into (or response coming back?) the second subnet.

[image: Network topology]

I have tried to set inbound and outgoing rule, allowing PuTTY by wizard in main firewall control panel and nothing has worked me. Please tell me what I have done wrong or how to set up it correctly.

I have tested that when firewall is completely disabled, communication works.

I have tested that Windows blocks all ports. I can't use FTP or Remote Desktop Protocol either.

Wireshark shows black lines with `TCP Retransmissions`, `TCP Surious Retransmission` and `TCP Dup ACK`. Between these lines are black ICMP redirects.

Comment: I enabled logging DROPed packets in Widows firewall and no entry is written when firewall block the communication.

Comment: Are you sure you applied the rules to the correct profile (i.e. private/public/domain)? What happens if you temporarily set inbound connections to be allowed by default?

Comment: Relus are set to all profiles. If I set allowing inboud connection by default it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a custom rule that allows all inbound traffic from a certain subnet. Open Windows Firewall with Advanced Security (`wf.msc`). Right-click *Inbound Rules*, then choose *Add Rule*.

1. On the *Rule Type* screen, choose *Custom*.
2. On the *Program* screen, choose *All programs*.
3. On the *Protocol and Ports* screen, leave the default values (any protocol).
4. On the *Scope* screen, leave the local IP set to *Any IP address*. Set the remote IP to *These IP addresses*. Click the Add button. In the *This IP address or subnet* field, type `192.168.0.0/24` to allow in all traffic from the two subnets. Click OK. **Caution:** This may expose the machine to attacks from other computers on the network. If possible, set more specific port/program rules.
5. On the *Action* screen, choose *Allow the connection*.
6. On the *Profile* screen, check the boxes corresponding to the profiles on which the rule should be active.
7. On the *Name* screen, enter an appropriate name and description (if you like), then click Finish to apply the rule.

Alternatively, you can use `netstat` or [TCPView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/tcpview.aspx) to figure out what specific connections are made, then create more specific firewall rules for those.

Comment: I set up rule as you described and nothing changed. On https://imgur.com/4dyc5FD you can see this rule. (my Windows is in Czech; Jakýkoliv and Vše means all, Povolit means allow, Ano means yes). Putty says `Network error: Software caused connection abort`. After every change I am restarting computer. There are one no value in column overrides. Every rule have this value set to no and I did not found how to change this value.

Comment: @Misaz Interesting. Do any other programs now work when connecting to that subnet? If so, [this other question](http://superuser.com/q/294824/380318) might help. Are there any Block entries in the list? Do you have any antivirus program that could be causing trouble?

Comment: no, I tested RDP and the same. There are just one rule blocking Node.js server on public profile. I added result of Wireshark to question while trying to connect to the server. The output is the same for SSH and RDP.

Comment: @Misaz ICMP redirects [can indicate less-than-ideal configuration](http://www.cymru.com/gillsr/documents/icmp-redirects-are-bad.htm). Are there other routers in play? Do the routers in between do any filtering? I'm also curious to see if anything happens if you change the firewall rule to `192.168.0.0/24`. If not, does adding an identical *outbound* rule have an effect?

Comment: I changed `192.168.0.128/25` in rule to `192.168.0.0/24` and that works! Thank you very much. The routers are just simple OpenWRT router with default firewall configuration.

Comment: Could you update answer with more informations about how can firewall cause ICMP redirects?

Comment: @Misaz I don't believe Windows Firewall can cause ICMP redirects; that was just another thing to check on your network. I did update my answer to include what solved the problem.