# Network Error: Software caused connection abort

Tags: networking, ssh, putty, vmware-workstation

I have Windows 10 as host O/S and Redhat-7 as guest O/S. Everything was working fine but one day I face error **Network Error: Software caused connection abort**. I have used bridged mode for the guest OS in VMware Workstation. I search with google spending around 3-4 hours but every solution provided and I got was bootless. For resolution, I again readded new ethernet but the problem still persists. I have exactly the same problem in link [PuTTY Network Error: Software caused connection abort](https://superuser.com/questions/294824/putty-network-error-software-caused-connection-abort) . I think of reinstalling the new O/S, but same error occurred with the newly installed O/S too. So any help from experts is highly appreciated.

Comment: @Will.Beninger thanks for the response, I was actually opening a new question that already existed, as the solution was not valid for me and I had traced out the solution that worked for me and was not able to post an answer to that question. Hence to share the solution that worked for me, I opened a new question on the same topic. I hope it will help others too.

Comment: I understand, but the criteria for answering a question (10 reputation) should probably not encourage then spawning off a second related question and self-answer. You're now over that threshold so I encourage you to post your answer over there and close up this question.

Comment: @Will.Beninger I am not opening a new question on the same topic for 1o reputation, but to share the solution that worked for me thinking will be helpful to others. I have posted my answer to the same question. And thanks for your suggestion and will close up this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was actually facing this issues many times. I searched with google many times but none of the was efficacious. I am actually answering this question here is that I was not privileged to answer this question to question [PuTTY Network Error: Software caused connection abort](https://superuser.com/questions/294824/putty-network-error-software-caused-connection-abort) hence I opened a new question to share the answer that worked for me and I hope it will also be helpful to others.

As DBA I have to visit clients and I have to set my networking configuration as per client premises. So whenever I leave the client premises and connect to another network via wireless and open VM I faced the same problem as stated in above link. So I thought for a while and checked my configuration for LAN Ethernet and Wireless Ethernet and I found a mismatch. As my VM would automatically use the physical ethernet among two for bridging. So when I reset the networking configuration for LAN/Wireless ethernet to DHCP it worked like charm and no more connection abort.