# Using PuTTY commandline for downloading file through SSH

Tags: command-line, ssh

I am investigating various options for writing a program that can automate download of files on a SSH server. I need it to automatically log in, navigate to different directories and download all files from there.

However, upon further thinking, it seems to me it may be easier to use PuTTY commandline to download all files from various folders to my own Windows computer.

I currently have a root account which I don't really want. (I am afraid something can go wrong, and I will be to blame.) Could I ask the server administrator to provide me with a limited account only with read privilege - and only to those directories? Would PuTTY still work or does it require something special on the SSH server to work? If so, that would be #1 way for me to solve my client's problem.

Answer (score 12):

[WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) is a good client for file transfer over SSH, and can work from windows cli or gui.

as for rights, no you don't need root to ssh, and if they reduce your privileges but grant you the required permissions on the files you need, that should work just fine for you. personally I don't allow root login via ssh, but I don't tend to run distros that enable a root account by default.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have upvoted it for now. More than anything I need commandline though. But I will check out WinSCP :)

Comment: winscp can be used via cli, so its just a matter of taste in clients.

Answer (score 8):

The PuTTY suite of utilities includes `pscp` which is equivalent to the OpenSSH `scp` command. You could use it like this:

```
pscp -pw password username@remote.server.com:/path/to/folder/* c:\local\folder
```

This will copy all the remote files in the folder specified to the local folder and would not require anything special on the remote end, aside from permitting the limited user ssh access, and access to the folder.

You would probably want to look into using public/private keys to avoid the need to put the password into your scripts - the second answer to this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/44106/is-there-a-way-to-auto-login-in-putty-with-a-password) shows you how.

Then you would use:

```
pscp -i /path/to/private.key username@remote.server.com:/path/to/folder/* c:\local\folder
```

To do this, the user account would have to have a `/home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, and the SSH server would have to permit public key authentication.

Comment: This appears to be an ideal solution. I will leave the quesion open for some time to receive more answers. (But I suspect I will be marking this as the answer.) I upvoted your answer for now :)