# Start an ssh connection with putty in windows without specifying credentials every time I log in

Tags: windows, putty

I want to start an ssh connection with putty in windows without specifying credentials every time I log in.

I want the lazy way to run an SSH without entering my super long complex password every time I log in. I know that possible solutions might defeat the purpose of having a super secure password but this might become handy in very controlled environments (self-justification).

Comment: You should have a look at [this reply](https://serverfault.com/a/940678/516502). It details how to reproduce the behavior of the linux tool `ssh-copy-id`, which deploys your public RSA key to the target server, so that it can identify you without the need for your password

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to "auto login" in PuTTY with a password?](https://superuser.com/questions/44106/is-there-a-way-to-auto-login-in-putty-with-a-password)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate an RSA private&public key pair and deposit the public key on the target machine, e.g. a router, and the private key in PuTTY. When connecting, the PC and router use the ssh key pair and you're logged in immediately. No interactive login.

Answer (score 0):

Create a regular windows shortcut and add the following as target:

```
Z:\location\PuTTY.exe -ssh user@server -pw mysupersecurepassword
```

Leave empty the `Start in` field from `Shortcut` tab at `Shortcut Properties` dialog window.